# Getting an Instagram feed in a mobile app without user interaction

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-graph-api

We are building a mobile app on behalf of a corporation. In the app, there needs to be a feed of the Corporation's Instagram feed. The app consumes a server side API where we will implement getting the Instagram feed data, which needs to have the following fields:

- Image URL
- Caption
- Post URL
- Timestamp

We need to use **long-lived access tokens** so that we can refresh them behind the scenes. A requirement of the app is that there should be no user authorization, since we are displaying a feed for the corporation (i.e. displaying a feed they own)

Can someone advise whether we should use the Basic Display API or the Instagram Graph API and explain how we do it?

The Instagram Graph API provides a way of getting the data we want but the problem lies with getting a long-lived access token, [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/long-lived-access-tokens/) state

> Long-lived tokens are valid for 60 days and can be refreshed as long as they are at least 24 hours old but have not expired, and **the app user has granted your app the instagram_graph_user_profile permission**. Refreshed tokens are valid for 60 days from the date at which they are refreshed. Tokens that have not been refreshed in 60 days will expire and can no longer be refreshed.

This appears to say user interaction is required although our app is a mobile app with a server-side API.

Can anyone help us?

Comment: This should not be done on the client-side in the first place in a scenario like this. You need a server-side component that makes the API calls using “your” access token then (that of the company, resp. whoever has access to the account), and have your mobile app request the data from there then.

Comment: This isn't client side. I will update my post to make it clearer

Comment: That doesn’t change the fact that _some_ user interation is required at some point, to generate an access token.

Comment: I hear what you are saying. There must be 1000's of apps out there for companies, that show their own Instagram feed. I don't see how the user of an app can authorise displaying the feed owned by the people who created the app?

Comment: Not talking about the mobile app user. You do this on the server side, using the authorization made by one of the people that have admin access to the account.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Instagram previously allowed this with no problem years ago, but it seems Facebook removed the ability to display **your own** feed on **your own** website without user interaction. I've been reading the documentation over and over. Has there been progress on a solution?